# Visualize error location in Visual Studio editor

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-errors

I'm looking for a way to visualize compiler errors in Visual Studio.

I'm working in C# and have "Underline errors in the editor" turned on in C#'s advanced text editor options. However the underlines are not very noticeable, so it's hard to catch them when scrolling through the code.

During build I get a list of compiler errors, but it would be nice to see the errors before building.

Currently for example I have to remove a class variable. The variable was used in several places, I could quickly fix all errors before building if there was a better way to see where they were.

One way would be to show a red tick in the scroll bar, but I didn't find anything like that in the preferences.

Is there a better way to see where the errors are in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Error List window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33df3b7a%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) should show you all the live semantic errors the IDE has found in the same way that it shows you errors the build found after a build.

The keyboard shortcut CTRL+SHIFT+F12 ([which is View.NextError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa%28VS.100%29.aspx#editors)) should cycle through the errors in that list and should adjust the code editor window to focus on the problem line.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried the Error List view, but I get a lag when I fix an issue while it's updating (basically the whole VS freezes). This is pretty odd because I'm on a Core2 Quad machine with 8Gb RAM. Do you experience this, too?

Comment: I haven't noticed much of a lag, but I tend to build fairly frequently anyway.  For some types of issue I can imagine that when it was fixed the IDE would have to re-parse a lot of the solution and I can imagine that taking quite a bit of time (and processor) if the solution is large.  Perhaps my expectations are set low enough that I don't see a lag even if there is one there?

Answer (score 1):

Simple. I use 2 extensions for that:

**Error Lens** (usernamehw.errorlens) for highlight the entire line and show on real time the error diagnostic

**Error Gutters** (igorsbitnev.error-gutters) for put error icons next of line number

Both look like this:

[image]